# Chocolate Sweetening in Ganache

Tags: cake

I need 1 more ounce of 60% bakers chocolate, but i only have unsweetened. How much powdered sugar should I add if I add 1 ounce of the unsweetened?
I'm trying to make a ganache.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Don't use powdered sugar, it has cornstarch and anti-caking agents in it. Use regular sugar instead.

Comment: I've posted an answer based on this info, but you could try posting a full recipe in addition to your substitution. That may help answerers provide a more precise substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it. It depends a little bit on the ratio of cream to chocolate you're using, but your ganache will turn out fine without adding sugar. If you're only using, say, 2 Oz of chocolate for your whole batch then it's worth adding some sugar to compensate. But if you're making enough to fill or cover something, the reduction in sugar would be hard to notice. You can (and in my opinion *should*) add a pinch of salt as well, which will help balance the flavors a little bit.

If the ganache does split or curdle, there are ways to fix it as well, usually by adding a little more hot cream at a time and whisking.

Answer (score 1):

60% chocolate is roughly the same as semi-sweet chocolate. In most recipes, you can substitute 1oz unsweetened chocolate + 1 Tablespoon granulated white sugar for 1 oz semi-sweet chocolate.

This substitution ratio may not always scale perfectly for baking (ex, 16 oz unsweetened + 1 cup sugar may not be the right substitution for 16 oz semi-sweet in a cake), but it works well for partial substitutions like yours, and in ganache, hot chocolate, etc.